# Model Backbone Views can't be removed from DOM at first Collection re-render

Tags: list, backbone.js, model, view

I've been facing an issue for the entire day now, and I'm kind of desperate! I'm pretty sure this will be simple for some Backbone experts around here...I'm new with Backbone and I might have not taken the best approach. Any help or advice will be awesome!

#### The Issue

After adding a new item to a collection, the collection is re-rendered, and I can see the new item added to my DOM.
If I click on the 'remove' button the event gets fired, and the new item get destroyed...BUT the element stays in the DOM. If I re render the page, (refresh or navigate somewhere else and come back) it's gone.

Whereas if I add a new item, navigate somewhere else right after my collection get rendered, then come back, and press 'remove', this time it gets destroyed AND removed from the DOM...
Any idea?

#### Adding a new item

```
save: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = form2js('deviceForm', '.', true);
    //Allow to create or edit a model;
    this.model.set(data);
    this.model = this.collection.create(this.model, {
        wait: true,
        success: function(){
            Utils.alert('success', 'Device has been added/edited');
            app.vent.trigger("devices:show");
        }
    });
}
```

this code is inside the view shown when I add a new item. When the new item gets added, it calls the function below. this.collection is my list of devices, reused inside the router.

#### Router

```
showDevices: function(){
    if (!this.devices){
        this.devices = new Devices();
        this.devices.fetch();
    }
    if (this.devicesList) this.devicesList.remove();
    this.devicesList = new DevicesView({collection: this.devices});
    $('.addPadding').hide().slideDown(1000, 'linear').html(this.devicesList.render().el);
},
```

I fetch the list just once and then reuse it every time I need it, avoiding unnecessary fetch. I clean the view if existing and instantiate a new one.

#### Collection (View)

```
initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "render", "addOne");

    this.collection.on('add', this.addOne);
    this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll);
},
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template);
    this.addAll();
    return this;
},
addOne:function(device){
    var devi = new DeviceView({model: device});
    this.$el.find(".devices-list").append(devi.render().el);
},
addAll: function(){
    this.collection.each(this.addOne, this)
}
```

no el attribute defined in my collection view. binding to collection event so that it gets rendered for a new item or fetch done.

#### Item view

```
tagName: 'tr',
events: {
    'click .remDevice': 'removeDevice',
    'click .editDevice' : 'editDevice'
},
template: _.template( template ),
initialize: function(){
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
},
render: function(){
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
},
removeDevice:function(){
    this.model.destroy();
}
```

My items are appended into a table, to the tbody element. This table is inside the template of my collection view. When I click on the remove button, the model is destroyed and the event is fired and call this.remove. But doesn't works when the collection is re rendered just after the creation of the item. Works after though...

Hope I gave enough information! Thanks a lot in advance!
PS: No error in the console and model + collections are populated in my debugger.

**EDIT:** this.remove is called at each click since my model gets destroyed every time. By overriding it and trying to remove manually the element with:

```
this.$el.remove();
```

makes no difference and doesn't show any error. this.$el contains my newly added element.

**EDIT 2**
A new clue: If I've a collection of 6 devices, add a 7th, then try to delete ANY of them, they got destroyed but not removed of the DOM unless I do the re render. So it's not linked to the NEW item only, but to the fact I added a new item to the collection, rendered it and try to delete one Item.
Also, the EDIT function still works on each item and redirect me to the right page with the right model to edit.

**LAST EDIT** I tried to empty the collection before to add new Items to avoid zombies...but didn't change anything. I hoped it would have avoided random side effects
in my Collection View

```
addAll: function(){
                this.$el.find(".devices-list").empty();
                this.collection.each(this.addOne, this)
            },
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why yet, but I don't like the line in your collection view `_.bindAll(this, "render", "addOne");` what is that line doing? does it work if you remove that?

Comment: From the code you supplied under **Collection** it seems that it's actually a view.

Comment: @MikeV, that line is equivalent to do _this = this, then use _this in my other functions. It just keeps my context to my view.
thanks for the edit! sorry about that

Comment: If you add a third `this` parameter to your `collection.on()` lines, you won't need the `_.bindAll` stuff. I try to stay away from using `_.bindAll`

Comment: A nice way to debug your ItemView/DeviceView would be to add `this.model.on('all', function(eventName){console.log(eventName)});` then check the console to see what events are being fired. You really just need to figure out why that `destroy` event is not trigging the `remove` function. Once you solve that, I think you'll solve your problem. I've deleted my answer, because it wasn't a solution.

Comment: thanks @CoryDanielson but you got me wrong. the destroy event does trigger the remove function. I added this.$el.remove() inside the remove function. Actually this function is even called multiple times because I don't remove the DeviceView I guess. But the This.$el.remove() removes the element only after I navigated somewhere else.

Comment: that doesn't make sense @_@ why wouldn't it remove it immediately?

Comment: you should drop a debugger in the `remove` function and then try to change the CSS on this.$el to see if it's really the correct element. try `this.$el.css('border', '1px solid red');` or something

Comment: I know it makes no sense! that's why I lost a day and ask on this website :(
Anyway I tried your idea, nothing gets surrounded with red, although this.$el IS my clicked element, and the clicked model gets destroyed. Like if the manipulated this.$el was not the one displayed...
I edited my question with more details though. It's not just the new added item that can't be removed after the first re render...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "dirty" way to fix my issue.
I had a breakpoints inside the 'remove function'. Visually comparing the this.$el and the line added to the table was the EXACT same line.

so I tried to do this:

```
$('.devices-list').find(this.$el)
```

But nothing was returned...which is crazy because they contain the exact same data! I assumed this.$el is rendered in a zombie version or something. I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the way the items are rendered to get to that point...but I definitely can't find out and I'm open to suggestions...

#### Solution

In my **Device View/Item View**, I edited these two functions, add to the tr the model id, then use jquery to find it in the DOM. like this I focus on existing elements and not $el which is cached jquery stuff...

```
render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.$el.attr('id', this.model.id);
        return this;
    },
remove: function(){
            var elem =  $('.devices-list').find('#'+this.model.id);
            $(elem).find('#'+this.model.id).slideUp(1000);
            $(elem).find('#'+this.model.id).remove();
        }
```

Hopefully someone will get a better idea or someone will be helped by my solution!